# Time Bar disappear migrating from cocos2d v1 to v2 (kCCProgressTimerTypeBar)

Tags: timer, cocos2d-iphone

I've a problem with a time bar. Until I was using cocos2d v1 all worked properly. When I've updated to v2 my bar disappear! It's a problem of the CCProgressTimer because, if I show the sprite without the time dependence all is working properly. So it's not a problem of positioning or of z.
The time is running out because, after a time implemented in the code, the game goes to gameover. The problem is just that the bar is not shown in the view.

This is the code in the init function:

```
    remainingTime = MaxTime;
    bar = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"barra.png"];
    bar = [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:barra];
    bar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;
    [bar setPosition:ccp(50 , size.height - 18)];
    [bar setPercentage:100];
    [self addChild:bar];
    NSLog(@"bar added! Here: %f %f", bar.position.x, bar.position.y);
```

I've tried to put `z:10000` but nothing...the timer goes on but the bar is hidden..

Comment: I remember CCPrigresstimer functionality was reduced in 2.0. Try using a different type of timer animation.

Comment: infact I use this type instead the older 'kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR'.. This should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the problem was an error in naming the sprite:

the correct code is:

```
barra = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"barra.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    mBarProgress = [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"barra.png"]];
    mBarProgress.position = ccp(50.0f*(mS.width/480.0f), 706.0f*(mS.height/768.0f)); 
    mBarProgress.midpoint = ccp(0.0f,1.0f);
    mBarProgress.barChangeRate = ccp(1,0);
    mBarProgress.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;

    [self addChild:mBarProgress z:4];

    [mBarProgress runAction:[CCProgressTo actionWithDuration:1.0f percent:99.0f]];
```

Comment: ehi thank you for the answer! but what type of file is FRAME_BUCKET_FILL?the problem is not in the sprite, just why if I remove the action all works perfectly!

Comment: try 99% in CCprogressTo action, is that displays?